# Set time for Alarm Manager to Stop (Android)

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm

I have a sound that is scheduled to play at 9 pm every day using the alarm manager class in android. How can I set a time for it to stop (for example, have it start at 2 pm and stop at 11 pm)?

```
    void playAudio() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent objIntent = new Intent(this, Sound.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent
            .getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, objIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}
```

Comment: If you plan to be woken up at the exact time and not minutes or hours later, you should NOT use inexact repeating.

Comment: Just an addition - there is no exact repeating since API 19. You have to use `setExact()` and reschedule your alarm when it fires. On the assumption that it's what you need.

Comment: @BladeCoder Would it really be hours later?

Comment: According to the docs yes, it can occur at any time between the exact time and the next iteration. So if you set 2PM everyday, the alarm may go off between 2PM and the next day at 2PM.